# SQL DISTINCT subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to make two queries into one?

Many thanks in advance

```
$colname_Recordset_hot = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Search'])) {
  $colname_Recordset_hot = $_GET['Search'];
}
$colnamef1_Recordset_hot = "%";
if (isset($_GET['f1'])) {
  $colnamef1_Recordset_hot = $_GET['f1'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_con_amazing, $con_amazing);
$query_Recordset_hot = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Hotel WHERE publish = 1 AND ad_country LIKE %s AND tag_1 LIKE %s OR ad_city LIKE %s OR category LIKE %s OR name LIKE %s OR tag_1 LIKE %s OR tag_2 LIKE %s OR tag_3 LIKE %s", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_Recordset_hot . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colnamef1_Recordset_hot . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_Recordset_hot . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_Recordset_hot . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_Recordset_hot . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_Recordset_hot . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_Recordset_hot . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_Recordset_hot . "%", "text"));
$Recordset_hot = mysql_query($query_Recordset_hot, $con_amazing) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset_hot = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset_hot);
$totalRows_Recordset_hot = mysql_num_rows($Recordset_hot);
mysql_select_db($database_con_amazing, $con_amazing);
```

I would like to get additional results on SELECT DISTINCT tag_1 column, but do not want to run same query twice.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want to get.

Comment: The question is unclear, at least to me. Can you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You could create a stored procedure that will return 2 different recordsets.

Comment: question edited with full code

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine the queries using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT CustomerName
FROM Customers
WHERE name LIKE %s
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT address
FROM Customers
WHERE name LIKE %s;
```

I'm not sure what advantage that has.